# How may to use Icon button as Togglebutton in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

In documentation say:

You can inherit the MyToggleButton class only from the following classes

[classes], but in they not **icon button**

Is there a way usage `IconButton` as `ToggleButton`? May extension, or anything?

If i use **Togglebutton** and **Iconbutton** together:

**.KV file:**

```
MyIconToggleButton:
    icon: 'home'
    pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
```

**.PY file:**

```
class MyIconToggleButton(MDFlatButton,MDToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Then error:

```
    raise ValueError(
 ValueError: Class <class '__main__.AddFavoriteIconToggleButton'> must be inherited from one of the classes in the list (<class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDFlatButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDRectangleFlatButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDRectangleFlatIconButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDRoundFlatButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDRoundFlatIconButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton'>, <class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDFillRoundFlatIconButton'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

> but in they not icon button

**Output:**

```
ValueError: Class <class '__main__.AddFavoriteIconToggleButton'> must be inherited from one of the classes in the list:
...,
<class 'kivymd.uix.button.MDFillRoundFlatIconButton'>
```

Comment: Don't understand